# How to let borrow checker know reference is no longer present?

Tags: rust

I have a problem with the borrow checker in the following scenario: First I store an immutable reference to a mutable variable `x`, which I later use elsewhere in my code. Now I come to a point where I want to change the value of `x`. Knowing that there is an immutable reference to it inside `foo.bar`, first I remove the reference by calling `foo.bar.clear()`.

Now that there are no immutable borrows, I'd expect that I can mutate the object, but that's not case. I assume that the problem is that the compiler has no way of knowing that `clear()` drops the references inside `foo.bar`, but I'm clueless how to proceed in this situation.

Minimal example:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: Vec<&'a i32>
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 42;
    let mut foo = Foo { bar: vec![&x] };
    // Do immutable stuff with foo.bar[0]... then:
    foo.bar.clear();
    x += 1;
    foo.bar.push(&x);
    println!("X is: {}", foo.bar[0]);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5f1c6d1a2b538c18598d5e6bf6310fc5)

Comment: TL;DR: The compiler doesn't know what the implementation of `clear` is.